# Android Drag and drop images on the Screen?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, imageview

I m working on project user to move the image in one position to Another position on the screen. I have written a sample code to move the image but the problem here is if I move one image the neighbouring image also starts moving.. Here is the sample code.any one Idea of this.

Main.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
   int windowwidth;
   int windowheight;    
   ImageView ima1,ima2;

   private android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams ;
   // private android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams ;
   //private android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams ;           

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);

         windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
         windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

         System.out.println("width" +windowwidth);
         System.out.println("height" +windowheight);             

         ima1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
         ima1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {  

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) ima1.getLayoutParams();

         switch(event.getAction())                   
            {
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:                          
                    break;     

              case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                    int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

              System.out.println("value of x" +x_cord);
              System.out.println("value of y" +y_cord);           

                    if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                        x_cord = windowwidth;
                       }
                    if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                        y_cord = windowheight;
                       }
             layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord-25;
             layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord-25;
             //   layoutParams.rightMargin = x_cord-25;
             //   layoutParams.bottomMargin = y_cord-25;
             ima1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                     break;
               default: break;
              }  
               return true;
            }
         });

         ima2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview2);
         ima2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {         

     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) ima2.getLayoutParams();
              switch(event.getActionMasked())
                 {
                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                       break;
                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                       int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                       int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

                       System.out.println("value of x1" +x_cord);
                   System.out.println("value of y1" +y_cord);                            

                        if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                            x_cord = windowwidth;
                        }
                        if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                            y_cord = windowheight;
                        }
                        layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
                        layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord - 75;
                        ima2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;
                    default: break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
       }
   }
```

main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <ImageView 
    android:layout_width="100dp" 
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageview1" 
    android:src="@drawable/image1"  />    
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100sp" 
    android:layout_height="100sp" 
    android:id="@+id/imageview2"
    android:src="@drawable/image2"   />             
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: here is example http://polamreddyn.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-drag-and-drop-images-in-one.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Write Below Code into your Activity File.

```
windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();


tv1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
tv1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {         

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        layoutParams1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tv1.getLayoutParams();
        switch(event.getActionMasked())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();
                if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                    x_cord = windowwidth;
                }
                if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                    y_cord = windowheight;
                }
                layoutParams1.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
                layoutParams1.topMargin = y_cord - 75;
                tv1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});

tv2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
tv2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {         

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        layoutParams2 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tv2.getLayoutParams();
        switch(event.getActionMasked())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();
                if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                    x_cord = windowwidth;
                }
                if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                    y_cord = windowheight;
                }
                layoutParams2.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
                layoutParams2.topMargin = y_cord - 75;
                tv2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

XML File:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="50sp" android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:id="@+id/image" android:src="@drawable/image">
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView android:layout_y="30dip" android:layout_x="118dip"
        android:layout_width="50sp" android:layout_height="50sp" android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:src="@drawable/image1">
    </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please see my edited answer and use imageview instead of textview.

Comment: use that one move only one image and move to some corners the size of the image is decrease and the second image is not possible to moving...

Comment: Above Code is Move Both Images Independent.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12532/discussion-between-nagarjunareddy-and-dipak-keshariya)

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.touchin/com.touchin.Main}: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.touchin.Main and  Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.touchin.Main

Comment: but this code is working for me, and please first clean your project and then run your project.

Comment: but before some minutes you tell me, "use that one move only one image and move to some corners the size of the image is decrease and the second image is not possible to moving", so is it working that time?

Comment: then problem is not in my code and if answer is helpful to you then accept it, so it may helpful to others.

Comment: hi finally got it but image moving right and bottom edges image size will by decrease how to solve this

Comment: sorry @NagarjunaReddy i don't know about this.

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy how did you solve your problem? i am facing the same problem

Comment: hello any one get solution!!!!!!! i m facing same problem on image move proper but another on move on one direction and also the size of image cange when i move it.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have put everything in a `LinearLayout`, which means you can't place the items where you want them, they are always one after the other. You can try to use a `RelativeLayout` instead. If that is not flexible enough, you should look at `Canvas`.

Comment: Just to clarify, you have 3 images on a 'RelativeLayout' and you want to move them separately over the screen, and they should be able to overlap each other, right?

Comment: YES three images in layout move them separately over the screen

Comment: You kept your onTouch code and just replaced the LinearLayout with a RelativeLayout and still more then one image is moving or what is the problem at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

the reason is that: your screen upload action_move too lazily.

in normal case , action move is uploading very frequently even if your finger don't move on the screen. but some phone screens are not so sensitive.

you can modify the threshold of your phone. It needs kernel support.

Comment: Dear this kind posting answer again is not allowed. I mean you are posting same answer with same content which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of alternating your code to manage multiple imageviews in a  RelativeLayout and random places. Also I added a better way of getting the window size, since `Display.getHeight()` is deprecated.

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13){
        android.graphics.Point p = new android.graphics.Point();
        this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(p); 
        width = p.x;
        height = p.y;
    }
    else{
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        width = display.getWidth();
        height = display.getHeight();
    }

    RelativeLayout rel = new RelativeLayout(this);
    rel.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)); 
    rel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);

    pic = new ImageView[10];
    layoutParams1 = new LayoutParams[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        pic[i] = new ImageView(this);
        pic[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.img);  
        pic[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  
        pic[i].setAdjustViewBounds(true);  
        pic[i].setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);  
        pic[i].setMaxHeight(88);  
        pic[i].setMaxWidth(100);
        pic[i].setMinimumHeight(88);
        pic[i].setMinimumWidth(100);
        pic[i].setTag(i);
        int x = rand.nextInt(width);
        while(x > width - 88){
            x = rand.nextInt(width);
        }
        int y = rand.nextInt(height);
        while(y > height - 100){
            y = rand.nextInt(height);
        }
        layoutParams1[i] = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) pic[i].getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams1[i].leftMargin = x;
        layoutParams1[i].topMargin = y;
        pic[i].setLayoutParams(layoutParams1[i]);
        pic[i].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {         

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int index = Integer.valueOf(v.getTag().toString());
                layoutParams1[index] = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                switch(event.getActionMasked())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                        int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();
                        if (x_cord > width) {
                            x_cord = width;
                        }
                        if (y_cord > height) {
                            y_cord = height;
                        }
                        layoutParams1[index].leftMargin = x_cord - 44;
                        layoutParams1[index].topMargin = y_cord - 50;
                        pic[index].setLayoutParams(layoutParams1[index]);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        rel.addView(pic[i]);
    }


    setContentView(rel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can avoid this problem by declaring the images programmatically .

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("image1", "drawable", getPackageName());
ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp = 
new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
imageView1.setLayoutParams(vp);        
imageView1.setImageResource(id);        
someLinearLayout.addView(imageView1); 

 int id = getResources().getIdentifier("image2", "drawable", getPackageName());
ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp1 = 
new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
imageView2.setLayoutParams(vp1);        
imageView2.setImageResource(id);        
someLinearLayout.addView(imageView2);
```

and add touch events to the added imageviews