# moving an image in drag and drop

Tags: android

I am making an android application in which i want to move the image from one cell to another cell. I am following the link [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html). the problem is I am making the class extends activity
while its extending the view and there its implementing. see below

my class

```
  public class GameActivity extends Activity
    implements OnTouchListener
```

class in example

```
  public class TouchExampleView extends View
```

its showing error on OnDraw() method. I could understand its a defined in view class but how could I implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Activity File.

```
windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();


tv1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
tv1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {         

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    layoutParams1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tv1.getLayoutParams();
    switch(event.getActionMasked())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
            int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();
            if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                x_cord = windowwidth;
            }
            if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                y_cord = windowheight;
            }
            layoutParams1.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
            layoutParams1.topMargin = y_cord - 75;
            tv1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
});

tv2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
tv2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {         

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    layoutParams2 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tv2.getLayoutParams();
    switch(event.getActionMasked())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
            int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();
            if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                x_cord = windowwidth;
            }
            if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                y_cord = windowheight;
            }
            layoutParams2.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
            layoutParams2.topMargin = y_cord - 75;
            tv2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
            break;
        default:
            break;
     }
     return true;
  }
});
```

XML File:-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <ImageView 
    android:layout_width="100dp" 
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageview1" 
    android:src="@drawable/image1"  />    
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="100sp" 
    android:layout_height="100sp" 
    android:id="@+id/imageview2"
    android:src="@drawable/image2"   />             
</RelativeLayout>
```

see this one

[Android Drag and drop images on the Screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027792/android-drag-and-drop-images-on-the-screen)