# ontouch event on two images

Tags: android

In my application I want to move,drag and zoom two images simultaneously, but I can able to move only one image on screen.If I am trying to select or touch second image... first image is selecting and performing move ,drag and zoom operations.Below is my code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.multotouch.R.id;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, OnClickListener{
     private static final String TAG = "Touch" ;
     Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
       Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
       ImageView view1,view2;
       Button b1;

       // We can be in one of these 3 states
       static final int NONE = 0;
       static final int DRAG = 1;
       static final int ZOOM = 2;
       PointF start = new PointF();
        PointF mid = new PointF();
        float oldDist = 1f;
       int mode = NONE;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        view2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        view2.setOnTouchListener(this);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);

        view1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        view1.setOnTouchListener(this);
     }
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

         switch(v.getId())
         {
         case R.id.imageView :
                view2.bringToFront();

              switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                            Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG" );
                            mode = DRAG;
                            break;
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                            mode = NONE;
                            Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE" );
                            break;
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            if (mode == DRAG) {
                                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                                        event.getY() - start.y);
                            }
                            else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                                float newDist = spacing(event);
                                Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                                if (newDist > 10f) {
                                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                    float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                            oldDist = spacing(event);
                            Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                            if (oldDist > 10f) {
                                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                                midPoint(mid, event);
                                mode = ZOOM;
                                Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM" );
                            }
                            break;
              }
               view2.setImageMatrix(matrix);
               dumpEvent(event);
              return true; // indicate event was handled

         case R.id.imageView2 :
                view2.bringToFront();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Hii image22",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG" );
                    mode = DRAG;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE" );
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == DRAG) {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                                event.getY() - start.y);
                    }
                    else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                        float newDist = spacing(event);
                        Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                        if (newDist > 10f) {
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    oldDist = spacing(event);
                    Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                    if (oldDist > 10f) {
                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                        midPoint(mid, event);
                        mode = ZOOM;
                        Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM" );
                    }
                    break;

          }


           view2.setImageMatrix(matrix);
           dumpEvent(event);
          return true; // indicate event was handled



         }
        return true;



     }


    private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        String names[] = { "DOWN" , "UP" , "MOVE" , "CANCEL" , "OUTSIDE" ,
                  "POINTER_DOWN" , "POINTER_UP" , "7?" , "8?" , "9?" };
               StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
               int action = event.getAction();
               int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
               sb.append("event ACTION_" ).append(names[actionCode]);
               if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
                     || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
                  sb.append("(pid " ).append(
                  action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
                  sb.append(")" );
               }
               sb.append("[" );
               for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
                  sb.append("#" ).append(i);
                  sb.append("(pid " ).append(event.getPointerId(i));
                  sb.append(")=" ).append((int) event.getX(i));
                  sb.append("," ).append((int) event.getY(i));
                  if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                     sb.append(";" );
               }
               sb.append("]" );
               Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
            }
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
           float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
           float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
           return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        }
    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
           float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
           float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
           point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
        }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == b1){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "haii",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            view1.setEnabled(false);
            view1.setEnabled(true);
            view1.setEnabled(false);
            view1.setEnabled(true);

        }

    }



}
main.xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         android:scaleType="matrix" >
   </ImageView>
     <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView2"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"

         android:scaleType="matrix" >
   </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_width="25dp"
         android:layout_height="25dp"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
         android:text="Button" 
         />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Use below link of my SO answer for drag two images, it will solve your problem.

[Drag Two Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027792/android-drag-and-drop-images-on-the-screen/11028521#11028521)

Comment: Welcome Satish, it's my pleasure.

Comment: One more question... How we can save this screen as an bitmap image..? After moving the image views.... whole screen (View have to save as bitmap image).... please don't mind... I am new to Android.. so I am  getting many issues like this..