# Pinch zoom of layout in android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, imageview, pinchzoom

I have a layout, which include two ImageViews. I want to create an easy way to include pinch zoom on ImageViews. I have watched some codes, but they work only on single ImageView.
Is it possible to make this work on a layout with ImageViews?

Answer (score 0):

Write Below Code for Drag two image into your Activity File and implement pinch zoom code into this.

```
windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();


tv1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
tv1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {         

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        layoutParams1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tv1.getLayoutParams();
        switch(event.getActionMasked())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();
                if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                    x_cord = windowwidth;
                }
                if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                    y_cord = windowheight;
                }
                layoutParams1.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
                layoutParams1.topMargin = y_cord - 75;
                tv1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});

tv2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
tv2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {         

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        layoutParams2 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tv2.getLayoutParams();
        switch(event.getActionMasked())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();
                if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                    x_cord = windowwidth;
                }
                if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                    y_cord = windowheight;
                }
                layoutParams2.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
                layoutParams2.topMargin = y_cord - 75;
                tv2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

XML File:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="50sp" android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:id="@+id/image" android:src="@drawable/image">
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView android:layout_y="30dip" android:layout_x="118dip"
        android:layout_width="50sp" android:layout_height="50sp" android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:src="@drawable/image1">
    </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And see below link for more information.

[Drag & Drop Two Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027792/android-drag-and-drop-images-on-the-screen/11028521#11028521)

Comment: i have implemented this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630373/android-image-view-pinch-zooming its not working for me....do u have any code pls help

Comment: @user960439 Do you have working pinch zoom code for one image?

Comment: @user960439 If possible post your full code in your question.

Comment: here is that code http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319401/Simple-Gestures-on-Android

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20787/discussion-between-user960439-and-dipak-keshariya)