# Why getLocationOnScreen(location) method gives the same result Altough the place of the image changes in Android?

Tags: android

I want to drag the image and find the last location of that image o the screen. I used the code below it gives the same locations every time Altough i drag it on the screen. How can I find the location of it what's wrong with this code. Thanks in advance..

```
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                             float distanceX, float distanceY) {

            view.onMove(-distanceX, -distanceY);

            int[] location= new int[2];

            view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
            Integer x=location[0];
            Integer y=location[1];

            Log.i("Location x1-->",x.toString());
            Log.i("Location y1-->",y.toString());

            return true;
        }

        public void onMove(float dx, float dy) {
            translate.postTranslate(dx, dy);
            invalidate();

        }
```

Thw logs shows this numbers all the time;

05-01 12:07:01.264: I/Location x1-->(397): 24

05-01 12:07:01.264: I/Location y1-->(397): 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onTouch` event and get the drag and drop positions as described in the following [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027792/android-drag-and-drop-images-on-the-screen).